# The binding of values to 'this' when calling a function with 'new'

Tags: javascript, binding, this

After reading about hoisting and how `this` gets bound, I don't understand the behavior of this snippet. Let's say you have this function:

```
function foo() {
    this.baz = "baz";
    console.log(this.baz);
}

var baz = new foo();
```

Now what I would expect is for the console to log "baz" because:

1. the `this` binding is the new object being created.
2. `this` is being assigned a property of `baz` with value "baz".
3. The value assignment is taking place before the console log.

Instead, the console is logging `undefined`.

What am I missing?

Comment: *"Instead, the console is logging undefined."* [No, it logs "baz"](http://jsfiddle.net/b37te9ks/), for exactly the reasons you listed. Points 1-3 are all spot-on.

Comment: I think he's confused because it also logs `undefined`, but it does this because the statement, `var baz = new foo()` does so.  For example, Chrome logs `undefined` if you type `var a = 5` into the console.

Comment: (Hoisting also doesn't come into the code above in any meaningful way.)

Comment: @JamesBrierley: Yes, if you paste that into the console, you're quite right. That could indeed be the confusion. With pictures, that might make a good answer. I don't think it's too speculative.

Comment: You guys are right. That's the behavior I see in the console but the logging does happen correctly when I run it through an IDE. Thank you, both.